# array sorting in DESC order

Tags: php, arrays

How can I sort inner array keys in DESC order?

I can sort 11, 12 in DESC order with `arsort()` but inner array remains same. I tried `array_multisort()`, `usort()` and others but without luck.

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [4] => apr11timetable.php
            [8] => aug11timetable.php
            [6] => jun11timetable.php
            [11] => nov11timetable.php
            [10] => oct11timetable.php
        )
    [12] => Array
        (
            [4] => apr12timetable.php
            [8] => aug12timetable.php
            [2] => feb12timetable.php
            [6] => jun12timetable.php
            [10] => oct12timetable.php
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [ksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php). `Arsort` will not sort your array properly.

```
<pre>
<?php
$array = Array(
    11 => Array(
        4 => 'apr11timetable.php',
        8 => 'aug11timetable.php',
        6 => 'jun11timetable.php',
        11 => 'nov11timetable.php',
        10 => 'oct11timetable.php'
    ),
    12 => Array(
        4 => 'apr12timetable.php',
        8 => 'aug12timetable.php',
        2 => 'feb12timetable.php',
        6 => 'jun12timetable.php',
        10 => 'oct12timetable.php'
    )
);

krsort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);

foreach ($array as &$arr) {    
    krsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
}

print_r($array);
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, why `Arsort` will not sort your array properly? Any technical problem?

Comment: There is not a technical problem. You can check PHP Doc for more details and try @air4x's snippet (http://codepad.org/ne2ldv9w) to see that the sorting is not proper with `arsort`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you want to sort in DESC order. Edited my answer. Just change `ksort` with `krsort` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is no simple function to accomplish that so I've come up with this code:

```
arsort($file_list);

foreach ($file_list as $key => $inner_array)
{
    krsort($inner_array);
    $file_list[$key] = $inner_array;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($file_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
foreach ($arr as &$ar) { arsort($ar); }
```

http://codepad.org/ne2ldv9w

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code:

```
array_walk($array,'krsort');
```